# Focus moves next tab if user press any key

Tags: vbscript

I tried making a script that should perform the following functions:

1. runs in background
2. focus moves to next tab if user press any key
3. run on windows platform.

I used the following code but its not working :(

Please correct me if I had made a error in code.

```
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim a
Do
  a = WScript.StdIn.Read(1)
  wshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Loop
```

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. `WScript.StdIn` is only available if you run the script with `cscript.exe`, and the script will only be able to read keystrokes if it's the active window (i.e. does not run in the background). Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: explain "focus moves to next tab if user press any key" - what is that supposed to mean? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Hi Friends, thanks for your feedback. The problem i want to solve is

Comment: Hi Friends, thanks for your feedback. I am handling compliance in my current company. I perform operational audits of 150 employees each month and each employee is evaluated in 4 different parameter. So the problem is that I personally need to enter scores on our official website          for example Adam - Efficiency- 5,  costing -4, team - 2, reporting - 3. So every time I enter score in one field I have to press tab key to move to next text box to enter further score.

Comment: What I want - The focus should move to next text box once score is entered. example if I write 4 in efficiency then just after pressing key 4 the focus should move to costing with out pressing tab key. I hope its clear now